# Are they any technical SNA tutorials that focus on real-world business problems?

Tags: social-network-analysis

Most of the technical (e.g. NetworkX, iGraph, Gephi) SNA tutorials I see focus on "toy" examples. They show how to run various algorithms, but it's not clear what real problems these would solve---which makes it all a little dry.

Does anyone know of tutorials (or other SNA learning resources) that explain how to use an analysis library/tool in the context of a real business need?